# Поменять цвет у спрайта из скрипта 2d toolkit unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как поменять цвет у tk2dsprite?
В свойствах скрипта tk2dsprite есть цвет, который можно менять из редактора, а как его менять из другого скрипта?

И каким образом можно менять цвет плавно, в течении одной секунды после запуска?

```
GetComponent<tk2dsprite>().GetComponent<Color>().a = 255
```

Не работает, говорит что 
это не переменная, поэтому поменять не может.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для изменения:

```
 Color _Color= GetComponent<tk2dsprite>().GetComponent<Color>();
 _Color = new Color(0.2F, 0.3F, 0.4F, 0.5F);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html

Для плавности: нужно в течении секунды менять значения rgba(в зависимости от необходимого цвета).

```
 void ChangeColor()
    {
       // Секунда(или несколько) делить на число - чем больше число тем плавней. 
       float time = 1 / 10; 
       float r = _Color.r + time
        if (_Color.r < 1)
        {
            _Color = new Vector4( r, _Color.g, _Color.b, _Color.a);
            Invoke("ChangeColor", time);
        }
    }
```

Запусти ChangeColor() в Start, если это скрипт "tk2dsprite". Или просто вызови один раз, если это другой скрипт.

Comment: Работает частично.
Цвет надо назначать таким образом 
`color = new Vector4(1, 1, 1, 1);
        _tk2dsprite.color = color;`